# Configuring Service Discovery for Azure in Hazelcast

Tags: azure, hazelcast, service-discovery

**The Problem:**
I'm setting up hazelcast AutoDiscovery feature to be used in Azure Environments. I am following the github document for the same: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-azure

But I am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.hazelcast.config.InvalidConfigurationException: Invalid configuration
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.loadDiscoveryStrategies(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:147)
>   .....
>   com.hazelcast.core.server.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:46)
>   Caused by: com.hazelcast.config.properties.ValidationException: There is no discovery strategy factory to create 'DiscoveryStrategyConfig{properties={group-name=****, client-secret=****, subscription-id=****, client-id=****, tenant-id=****, cluster-id=****}, className='com.hazelcast.azure.AzureDiscoveryStrategy', discoveryStrategyFactory=null}' Is it a typo in a strategy classname? Perhaps you forgot to include implementation on a classpath?
>       at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.buildDiscoveryStrategy(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:186)
>   ...

I have tried the following properties:

```xml
     <azure enabled="true">
          <client-id>****</client-id>
          <client-secret>****</client-secret>
          <tenant-id>****</tenant-id>
          <subscription-id>****</subscription-id>
          <cluster-id>****</cluster-id>
          <group-name>****</group-name>
     </azure>
```

Since This was not working I even tried using discovery strategy with the following code snipppet:

```xml
 <discovery-strategies>
                <!-- class equals to the DiscoveryStrategy not the factory! -->
                <discovery-strategy enabled="true" class="com.hazelcast.azure.AzureDiscoveryStrategy">
                    <properties>
                        <property name="client-id">****</property>
                        <property name="client-secret">****</property>
                        <property name="tenant-id">****</property>
                        <property name="subscription-id">****</property>
                        <property name="cluster-id">****</property>
                        <property name="group-name">****</property>

                    </properties>
                </discovery-strategy>
            </discovery-strategies>
```

Even switched the value of class from:
`class="com.hazelcast.azure.AzureDiscoveryStrategy"`
to 
`class="com.hazelcast.azure.AzureDiscoveryStrategyFactory"`

I have tried the above with **hazelcast versions 3.12.2, 3.12.1, 3.12 and 3.11.4** and all are giving same result.

Please suggest what I am doing incorrectly and what else is required.

Comment: Hi, Have you included hazelcast-azure.jar and its dependencies in your classpath? That is the problem you are having most probably.

Where are you deploying Hazelcast on Azure... just VMs? You can always configure TCP IP if IPs are well known for you in advance. And if you are deploying into kubernetes, you can use hazelcast-kubernetes plugin.

Comment: I am deploying directly on VM in an Auto Scaling environment to support for HA so IP's cannot be known in advance.
Regarding hazelcast-azure.jar, I guess I haven't done that. Can you please help me in that direction about how can I set it up. I haze hazelcast from official tar fetched from its website.